# Trusted sites in web.config

Tags: iis, web-config, trust

I'm working on an enterprise intranet .NET web application that needs several domains to be added to trusted sites to work properly (in Windows Internet Options). Is it possible to do this from web.config (rather than advising users to change their browser configuration)?

Thanks

Comment: Impossible. Please use domain policies to push to every browsers (IE/Edge/Chrome). Firefox has its own push system.

Answer (score 0):

May I know why are you going to add trusted website for clients?Did you get anything blocked?

Trusted sites are totally client side configuration.Its dangerous if server side can control your trusted site list.
 So we can't do this via remote IIS server. Please promote trusted websites from ADDS group policy.What you can do from server side is just use a valid CA certificate for your website to make the connection secure. 
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/0baa6428-bf48-4e8a-82e1-b961918090d9/how-to-add-trusted-sites-to-group-policy?forum=winserverGP

Comment: This is an enterprise software with some legacy components which rely on a series of services that are available from different domains, each with its own certificate. Being able to control this from web.config would be very useful in this case, but I understand the security implications. Thanks.